# Jquery animate or slideup within fadeout in a timer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a table [(bootstrap-table)](https://bootstrap-table.com/) that i need to delete the first row every 2,5 seconds.

Before deleting it i would like to `fadeOut` and then `slideUp` or animate height to 0.

My problem is that the fading goes well but animate/slideUp happens instantly.

Row is successfully removed though.

Fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/earthdog/vzj79cud/2/)

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: show the whole code

Comment: @palaѕн Added fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fadeOut()` sets a `display: none` on the element and you will see the sudden jump when it ends. After that setting any property will not show any visual changes.

You can do something like animating `opacity` first, then the `height`:

```
function fadeoutFirst() {
    timerFadeout = setInterval(function () {
        $('#table tbody tr:first').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).animate({height: 0}, 1000, function () {
                $(this).remove();
                if ($('#table tbody tr').length <= 10) {
                    stopfadeoutFirst();
                }
            });
        });
    }, 2500);
}
```

---

**Edit:** As it turns out, animating on `tr`/`td` directly for `height` is not possible, so a workaround is to insert a temporary `div` inside it and animate its `height`, at the same time animating `padding` of the `td`

See it working below:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    timerFadeout = setInterval(function() {
      let row = $('#table tbody tr:first')
      row.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000
      , function() {
        
        let col = row.find('td')
        
        col
        .wrapInner('<div/>')
        .find("div")
        .animate({ height: 0 }, 1000)

        col.animate({ padding: 0 }, 1000
        , function() { row.remove() })
        
      })
    }, 2500)
  });
       
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<table id="table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>COLUMN</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @e4rthdog Check edit to my answer, I'm adding an explanation